# Reading Badly Formatted Data

Tags: sas

I am trying to understand how to read badly formatted data in SAS. bellow is the snippet, and the beginnings of my attempt. I also tried doing an if statement but wasn't sure how to declare a format for each line. for example:

`if _N_ then [format for this line goes here];`

```
data prob2;
length name $ 8 ;
infile rawdata(Group2.txt) truncover;
input Code Name X Y Z;
proc print data=prob2;
run;
```

Sample data:

```
10 Arnold 123 21 333
20 Barbara 11  387
30  176 265 3876
 Daniel 154  39876
50 Elmo 176 256 33
60 Fifi 198 298
70 Gizmo  288 354
80    376
90 Isaac 100 267 322
```

expected output:

```
Code  Name     X    Y     Z
-----------------------------
10 | Arnold | 123 | 21 | 333
20 | Barbara|  11 | 387|  .
30 |     .  |  176| 265| 3876
 . | Daniel |  154|  39| 876
50 |  Elmo  |  176| 256| 33
60 |  Fifi  |  198| 298|  .
70 |  Gizmo |  288| 354|  .
80 |    .   |  376|  . |  . 
90 |  Isaac |  100| 267| 322
-----------------------------
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried as well as what you expect as output. For example, what should the second last line be? Can you assume that a space is the delimiter?

Comment: I have posted, now, both. what i tried is the snippet above the datalines, and the last block is the expected output.

Comment: Try `infile rawdata(Group2.txt) delimter=' ' dsd;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

david25272's Solution is working.

```
option missing=.;

data begin;  
    INFILE DATALINES  DLM=' ' dsd;
    input Code  Name  $ X Y Z;  
    datalines; 
10 Arnold 123 21 333
20 Barbara 11  387
30  176 265 3876
 Daniel 154  39876
50 Elmo 176 256 33
60 Fifi 198 298
70 Gizmo  288 354
80    376
90 Isaac 100 267 322
;
run;
```

Produces

```
Code    Name    X   Y   Z
10  Arnold  123 21  333
20  Barbara 11  387 .
30      176 265 3876
.   Daniel  154 .   39876
50  Elmo    176 256 33
60  Fifi    198 298 .
70  Gizmo   288 354 .
80      376 .   .
90  Isaac   100 267 322
```

However this is space sensitive and if possible, I'd suggest adding a delimiter to your in data. Pretty easy with simple replace function.

Edit: Found a wonderful paper on inputting data: 
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/253-29.pdf